# How to read table row height for ppt table using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have table in one of my ppt slide, my requirement is to read the height of table's row, so if the row is going out of that particular slide i can remove it, the height will vary base on the text in it.

I tried reading like these but for some reason not getting the accurate output:

```
int totalRows = table.getNumberOfRows();

double rowHeight = 0;
for(int t =0; t< totalTableRows; t++)
{
    //logic to read height of row
    rowHeight  += table.getRows().get(t).getCells().get(0).getAnchor().getHeight();

    //logic to remove row.
            if(rowHeight  > slideHeight)
            {
                for(int remove = t;t< totalRows; t++)
                {   
                    table.removeRow(remove);
                }
            }
}
```

Note: some rows and column has merged cells as well.

Comment: What about using [XSLFTableRow.getHeight](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTableRow.html#getHeight--)?

Comment: @AxelRichter i already tried this one before but the thing is whenever it is  encountering a merged row, it is reading them as individual row and it's returning the height but in my case if any cell in the row is merged it should consider that as a single row.

Comment: "if any cell in the row is merged it should consider that as a single row": How should that be? If you have 3 columns and 2 rows and first column spans both rows, the table still has 2 rows, hasn't it?

Comment: But, For some reason those merged rows are causing problems when I'm trying to read their height.

Comment: "But, for some reason ...":  Then please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows that issue. Else no help is possible.